# delete all documents with doc Id in subcollection across the root collection

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following structure

(Employees) -> emailId -> (lists) -> listId  .... then all fields

Basically if I need to get all the lists that employees have then I can simply go by the email Id and access all the documents under lists.

Employees can belong to the same list

Now the issue is if a list needs to be deleted. Is there a "query" that I can do to delete listId from all documents with the intended listId from all employees.

If not how would this structure be changed accordingly?

The backup option is have another root collection which has the listId and all its employees. In this case I need to do like 40 deletes (every employee I have to access indivudally to delete the list).

I  hope there is a cleaner solution

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires one query for each separate collection (or subcollection, it doesn't matter) that you want to read or write in some way.  You cannot affect or aggregate across collections in any way.

Comment: I see. Is this structure of doing things frown upon? I can imagin this situation to be common where one need to delete/update leaf document at the end of structure and it exists across multiple roots as well

Comment: Model your data in such a way that satisfies the queries you intend to perform on it.  That's the only real advice.  You just need to know the advantages and limitations of the underlying storage system.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it is catch 22, satisfying one query will add complexities on the opposing query in such situations. But like you said, I guess that's the limitation and will have to work around it.

Comment: You can always duplicate your data to satisfy multiple kinds of queries.  That is common with NoSQL.